# iOS: Localization confessions

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I have an application, that should have localization.

After a while I found [good tutorial project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial) for localization.

But it doesn't use any tool for localization, only by **Xcode**.

Should I use Apple's tools like **AppleGlot** for localization or only **Xcode**. (by adding **localizable.string**)?

AppleGlot provides many glossaries, but if I have only some words for translating?

In which case one or another way is preferable?

Comment: I use localizable.strings and I localize some xibs or storyboards too

Comment: I've used localizable strings and localized the xibs.  However, if I were to do it over again, I'd put everything in localizable.strings - it presents a much simpler interface in Xcode and it means far fewer files you need to keep track of with the translator.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the only way to do localization properly in iOS is through Xcode. You need to add NSLocalizedString macro to all your strings, externalize them using genstrings, and then have the Localizable.strings file translated. There is a step by step tutorial here:

http://www.ibabbleon.com/iphone_app_localization.html

As for a glossary, there is a public one produced by translators here:

http://www.ibabbleon.com/glossary

Although not made by Apple it's much better than AppleGlot because it focuses on iPhone terminology, and not Mac OS X.